# Why is this schema not storing the drop-down values to MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, express, pug, html-select, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to store `branch`, `year`, `semester` and `subject` to the database. But it only stores the value `name`. I added the value `name` just for testing purposes to know whether my schema is storing anything at all. But it stores `name` but not any other field.

Here's the schema:

```
const PaperSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, maxLength: 100},
    branch: {type: String, maxLength: 100},
    year: {type: Number, minLength: 4, maxLength: 4},
    semester: {type: Number, minLength: 1, maxLength: 1},
    subject: {type: String, maxLength: 100}
});
```

And this is the pug view for the above schema:

```
input#name(type="text" name="name")
                                label.fs-5.fw-normal.mt-2(for='branch') Branch
                                    select.form-select.my-1#branch(style="width:10rem;" required="")
                                        option(value="") Select
                                        - var branches = ['Computer Science & Engineering', 'Electronics & Communication Engineering', 'Electrical Engineering', 'Mechanical Engineering', 'Civil Engineering'];
                                        each branch in branches
                                            option= branch
                                
                                label.fs-5.fw-normal.mt-2(for='year') Year
                                    select.form-select.my-1#year(style="width:10rem;" required="")
                                        option(value="") Select
                                        - var year = 2023;
                                        while year >= 2019
                                            option= year--

                                label.fs-5.fw-normal.mt-2(for='semester') Semester
                                    select.form-select.my-1#semester(style="width:10rem;" required="")
                                        option(value="") Select
                                        - var semester = 1;
                                        while semester <= 8
                                            option= semester++

                                label.fs-5.fw-normal.mt-2(for='subject') Subject
                                    select.form-select.my-1#subject(style="width:10rem;" required="")
                                        option(value="") Select
                                        option Computer Science & Engineering
                                
                                input.btn.btn-primary.mt-3(type="submit" value="Submit")
```

I'm new to this platform so I might be lacking in SOPs. But I really need help.

I ran the node server and filled up the form. It only saves the `name` field and not any other field.

Comment: It would be helpful to know how you submit the form and how you catch the fields on the server side.

Comment: I'm really sorry.. but I don't think I get your question. What exactly do you want me to tell or show? Some other part of my JS code.. or something else?

Comment: I mean, you submit the form and in the backend you receive the form data. What exactly are you doing at this point?